# Can't see directory/Can't uncheckout

Tags: clearcase

When I do "ct lsco -a" I can see that I have three checkouts. But they don't show up in xclearcase, and the directories aren't visible from the command line.

```
ct lsco -a | grep hendrixjl
--07-29T15:32  hendrixjl  checkout directory version "/vobs/CORE/CORE_APPS/src/mapmgr_decoupled@@/main/rel_core_0.5.0.0__int/fea__cr_54__0.5.0.0_decouple_map_manager/3/icondetails_decoupled" from /main/rel_core_0.5.0.0__int/fea__cr_47__0.5.0.0_ui_decouple/0 (unreserved)
--07-29T15:32  hendrixjl  checkout directory version "/vobs/CORE/CORE_APPS/src/mapmgr_decoupled@@/main/rel_core_0.5.0.0__int/fea__cr_54__0.5.0.0_decouple_map_manager/4/overlays" from /main/rel_core_0.5.0.0__int/fea__cr_47__0.5.0.0_ui_decouple/0 (unreserved)
--07-29T15:32  hendrixjl  checkout directory version "/vobs/CORE/CORE_APPS/src/mapmgr_decoupled@@/main/rel_core_0.5.0.0__int/fea__cr_54__0.5.0.0_decouple_map_manager/4/overlays/main/rel_core_0.5.0.0__int/fea__cr_54__0.5.0.0_decouple_map_manager/1/images" from /main/rel_core_0.5.0.0__int/fea__cr_47__0.5.0.0_ui_decouple/0 (unreserved)
[hendrixjl@BA-JBCP-HENDRIX CORE]$ cd /vobs/CORE/CORE_APPS/src/mapmgr_decoupled
[hendrixjl@BA-JBCP-HENDRIX mapmgr_decoupled]$ ls
Makefile  ascope_translator  common_decoupled  displaySA_decoupled  filters  mgr_decoupled  unit_test
[hendrixjl@BA-JBCP-HENDRIX mapmgr_decoupled]$ ct unco .
cleartool: Error: No branch of element is checked out to view "cc-svr:/data/cc_store/viewstore/hendrixjl/fea__cr_47__0.5.0.0_ui_decouple__hendrixjl_view.vws".
cleartool: Error: Unable to find checked out version for ".".
[hendrixjl@BA-JBCP-HENDRIX mapmgr_decoupled]$ ct unco icondetails_decoupled
cleartool: Error: Element name not found: "icondetails_decoupled".
[hendrixjl@BA-JBCP-HENDRIX mapmgr_decoupled]$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those directories are checked-out in parent directories which are not visible/selected by your current view, probably because they have been removed (rmnamed).

That means the checked-out versions are not accessible from this view.

However, a potential workaround is to search for those same checked-out directories from the GUI "find checkouts" window: there you can select the checked-out element (file or directory) and select "undo checkout".

Another workaround is to go to the full extended path of that directory in a dynamic view: you will then be able to "`cleartool unco`" the directory.

```
cd /vobs/CORE/CORE_APPS/src/mapmgr_decoupled@@/main/rel_core_0.5.0.0__int/fea__cr_54__0.5.0.0_decouple_map_manager/3
cleartool unco icondetails_decoupled
```

In any case, whenever you don't see an element, the first think to do is a version tree of the **parent directory** of that element, in order to check if the missing element has been rmname'd in one of the version of said parent directory.